# $sample return unique docs mongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

La situación es esta, tengo una colección de logotipos de ** clientes ** y un cliente puede tener más de un logotipo.
Estoy tratando de obtener logotipos aleatorios (puede ser más de uno dependiendo del valor de `` cant```) con la condición de que el cliente asociado con ese logotipo esté en una arreglo de clients_ids, esto ya funciona.
El problema es que quiero que sean únicos y la consulta de mongoDB a veces devuelve 2 o más logotipos del mismo cliente

The situation is this, I have a collection of logos from **clients**, and a client can have more than one logo.
I'm trying to retrieve random logos (it can be more than one depending on the value of `cant`) with the condition that the client associated with that logo is in an array of clients_ids, this works already.
The problem is that I want them to be unique and the mongoDB query sometimes return 2 or more logos of the same client

```
Publicidad.Schema
{
   ...,
   cliente: cliente_id
}
const ids = [array of client ids from another collection]
const logos = await Publicidad.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $and: [{ cliente: { $in: ids } }, { activo: true }, { canal: "Logo" }],
      },
    },
    { $sample: { size: cant } },
  ]);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a es.stackoverflow ¿Podrías hacer tu pregunta en español por favor?

Comment: Ya lo edite al español. Gracias.